# Converting Array Of String to Double and then calculating the sum in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have an array of Strings that i would like to convert to Double. Then i would like to add each item in the array together and get the sum.

[image]

this is my code so far, After enumerating the array I'm having issues adding all of them together.

[image]

Comment: Batter to add the code. not the images.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

update: **Xcode 10.1 • Swift 4.2.1 or later**

```
let strings = ["1.9","2.7","3.1","4.5","5.0"]
let doubles = strings.compactMap(Double.init)
let sum = doubles.reduce(0, +)

print(sum) // 17.2
```

---

If you dont need the intermediary collection

```
let sum = strings.reduce(0) { $0 + (Double($1) ?? .zero) }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very helpful. Please include some explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array, 
for each string, convert the string to double using:

```
Double(string:String)
```

Then add each to the tally

```
var strings:[String] = ["1.3", "1", "8", "5", "bad number"]

var tally = 0.0
for eachString in strings{
    // Convert each string to Double

    if let num = Double(eachString) { //Double(String) returns an optional.
        tally += num
    } else {
        print("Error converting to Double")
    }
    // Another way to convert if you don't need error handling 
    // NSString.doubleValue will just return 0.0 on a bad string.      
    // let num=(eachString as NSString).doubleValue
    // tally += num

}
print(tally)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `map` (iterate and convert each value in array) all values in array to `Double` and then `reduce` all `Double` values with start value `0` and closure (in your case it's just an operator) `+`.

> `reduce` a collection of elements down to a single value by recursively applying the provided closure.

```
let stringDoubles = ["2.9","3.1","1.7","9.5","5.6"]
let sum = stringDoubles.map { Double($0)! }.reduce(0, combine: +)
print(sum) // "22.8". If start value was, for example, 10, print(sum) => "32.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to your first part of your question in Swift 2.0:

> I have an array of Strings that i would like to convert to Double. Then i would like to add each item in the array together and get the sum.

```
let myStrings  = ["2", "3","5.6", "4", "6"]

let doubles  = myStrings.map { (s : String) -> Double in
  if let d = Double(s){
    return d
  }
  return 0.0
}

let sum = doubles.reduce(0.0, combine: {(sum: Double, item:Double) ->Double in
          return sum + item
})
```