# Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'String' Swift

Tags: swift, string, double

I got lat long from API in string format now i want to change it to double.

```
let latitudeAll = [String]()

let double = 

NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(latitudeAll)?.doubleValue
```

Comment: let double = Double(latitudeAll[0])

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366645/converting-array-of-string-to-double-and-then-calculating-the-sum-in-swift

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the particular array object with its index.

```
if latitudeAll.count > 0 {
    let double = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(latitudeAll[0])?.doubleValue
}
```

if you want `Double` Array from `String` array use this.

```
var doubleArr =  latitudeAll.map { Double($0) }
```

Here `doubleArr` is type of `[Double?]`

Comment: Your doubleArr is type of `[Double?]`